# Mvc 3: Using calculated fields in a model and displaying calculated fields in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to show the result of a stored procedure and make it look like the attached image. I know I have to create a model that will look like this

```
public class MyInvoice
{
    public DateTime invoiceDate { get; set; }
    public string invoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double amountDue { get; set; }
}
```

The Other amount will be a total of some fields
Total Due will be a sum of Other amount and total sum of amount due

I will need to pass just one model to my view. How can I include the calculated fields in my model?
I will like to have access to the calculated fields in my view. 
Do I just add other amount and total due to my model?

I also know I have to write something like this in my action result method but not sure how to handle
other amount and total due since they are not coming from the database.

```
IEnumerable<MyInvoice> model = _myInvoiceService.GetInvoice()
return view(model);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The proper way would be to create a `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<MyInvoice> MyInvoices {get; set;}
    public double OtherAmount {get; set;}
    public double TotalDue {get; set;}
}
```

Then map your `Invoices` to the `ViewModel`:

```
IEnumerable<MyInvoice> model = _myInvoiceService.GetInvoice();
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
myViewModel.MyInvoices = model;
myViewModel.OtherAmount = //whatever you want here;
myViewModel.TotalDue = //total due here
return View(myViewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

You normally won't go to you view with a model, you'll go with a ViewModel instead.

Create a secondary class for this, where you can compute whichever values you like:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public MyInvoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public double SomeComputedAmount { 
    get { 
         return Invoice.SomeValue + Invoice.OtherValue; 
    }
    public List<InvoiceLineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

And change your code to match the following in your action method:

```
List<InvoiceViewModel> model = null;
foreach(var invoice in _myInvoiceService.GetInvoice())
{
  model.Add(new InvoiceViewModel { Invoice = invoice };
  // etc...
}

return view(model);
```

Finally, have your view accept an IEnumerable of InvoiceViewModel.